# Missing credentials for Python Client Library call in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I am trying to get sample code for the python client library to work from Google Cloud Datalab. The program looks like this:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

def get_client():
    """Builds a client to the dataproc API."""
    dataproc = googleapiclient.discovery.build('dataproc', 'v1')
    return dataproc

def list_clusters(dataproc, project):
    result = dataproc.projects().regions().clusters().list(
        projectId=project,
        region='global').execute()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
        dpc = get_client()
        project='my-sandbox1-165203'
        res = list_clusters(dpc, project)
        print res
```

Following the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-library-example) it works just fine from my local system that has the Google Cloud SDK installed. I also got it to work from a Compute Engine instance with Cloud API access scopes enabled to 'Allow full access to all Cloud APIs'. The Datalab Compute Engine instance does have 'Allow full access to all Cloud APIs' as well as I can see from the console. But when I run the code from Cloud Datalab

`dataproc.projects().regions().clusters().list(projectId=project,region='global').execute()`

fails with

`HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-sandbox1-165203/regions/global/clusters?alt=json returned "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.">`

And as far as I can see the datalab code runs with the default service account as '!gcloud auth list' shows.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: in what environment are you getting this error from? you might have to add the service account credential object on your own depending on your environment

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I imported the key file generated for the default service account in Cloud Datalab but it still does not work. It is OK though ... bigger picture is that I learned that for using Cloud Datalab with Dataproc  you need to run Datalab on the master node of the Dataproc cluster as per [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/datalab)